# Inequalities between areas of triangles in an Euclidean 4-simplex?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, simplex, geometric-inequalities

The 10 edge lengths of a 4-simplex with vertices $0,1,2,3,4$ satisfy the inequality that the eigenvalues of the matrix $M$ with elements $$M = [m_{ij}] = l_{0i}^2+l_{0j}^2-l_{ij}^2$$ is positive definite. $l_{ij}$ is the length of an edge connecting vertices $i$ and $j$. This actually holds in general for an $n$-simplex. A 4-simplex also has 10 areas of triangles.

My question is that given rather 10 areas of triangles of the 4-simplex, is there an inequality between only the areas to ensure that they form the simplex?

Comment: Thinking out loud ... Menger's Theorem says that six edge-lengths determine a non-degenerate tetrahedron ($3$-simplex) when the ostensible face-areas and volume are positive. I haven't checked, but an edge-based test for $4$-simplex viability may amount to requiring that triangle areas, tetrahedral volumes, and the full $4$-volume be positive. Translating to face-based conditions is problematic (well, we get the triangle areas for free :), because face areas alone are already insufficient to guarantee *tetrahedral* viability. ... Can you provide some context about what you want to achieve?

Comment: FYI: In the note ["A Hedronometric Theorem of Menger" (PDF link via daylateanddollarshort.com](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/mathdocs/A-Hedronometric-Theorem-of-Menger.pdf), I discuss a tetrahedral viability test based on candidate face and "pseudo-face" areas (four of the first, three of the latter).

Comment: To put the question in context, I am wondering the following: given 10 areas, is there a condition among the areas that tells you whether they are belong to a geometric 4-simplex or not.

Comment: Thanks @Blue.. I'm a looking for a necessary condition for a 4-simplex in terms of only areas. There's an inequality for volumes of $n-1$ sub-simplices.. $2V_i< V_i +\cdots V_n$. For a tetrahedron this is a necessary condition in terms of areas. A necessary condition of a 4-simplex is given in terms of tetrahedral volumes. I am looking for a condition in terms of all areas instead of volumes..